# How can i retrieve the tool tip information in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In eclipse, if we are focusing any of the variable or instances or whatever using our mouse pointer we will be notified with some information about the focused thing. Is it possible to to fake that mouse move and obtain the tool tip information in our own plugin project?

If possible can you please say me some way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance,
Easwar

Comment: A little unclear on what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to add a new kind of hover info inside of a Java editor, or are you trying to use the information that a Java hover would provide inside of your own editor/view?

Comment: I am actually writing a plugin which needs the information of the tool tip. For example,  we cant able to know information about the local variables using our present java apis like reflection. I can able  to see the information of the local variables when I move my mouse pointer on the variable or object. I need that info to be obtained automatically. Is it possible to fake the mouse move and retrive the information.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces to what you are looking for:

1. figuring out what thing is at a given location.  For this, you need to call the API method: `org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICodeAssist.codeSelect(int, int)`.  If you have a file handle, then you can do somthieng like this:

   IFile file = getFile();
   ICompilationUnit unit = JavaCore.create(file);
   IJavaElement[] elts = unit.codeSelect(start, length);

Then, once you have the Java elements, you need to extract the Javadoc information from them.  This is a little bit less straight forward, but you can have a look at the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover` class, specifically the `getHoverInfo` class.

If you just want the javadoc, then you should have a look at the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2` class.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to provide tooltips in SWT:

- You can set it using `control.setToolTipText(text)`.
- You can add a `SWT.MouseHower` listener and show your own tool tip information when invoked - really anything. This method is used by `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip`.

In the first case, you can retrieve the tooltip with `control.getToolTipText()`. In the later case, you cannot find the text programmatically... it does not even have to be a string...

You can show the tooltip - for both methods above - using `Display.post(Event)` by first positioning the mouse with `SWT.MouseMove` and then wait a second with `Display.timedExec(Runnable)`.